# SignalR cross-domain javascript client hub start method fails only when client methods are subscribed

Tags: javascript, signalr

SignalR cross-domain javascript client **hub start method** fails only when client methods are subscribed. If client methods are not subscribed, **hub start is successfully called** and the **server methods are called successfully**.

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://my-cross-domain.com:876/signalr';
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

chatHub.client.displayMessage = function (windowID, message) {
    alert("test");
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    alert("Connected");
});
```

If chatHub.client.displayMessage is not subscribed. It starts and connects well.

But if the client method is subscribed, it doesn't connect and throws the

**no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource**
kind of error.

**Failure: While subscribing Client Methods**
[image: **Failure: While subscribing Client Methods**]

**Success while NOT subscribing Client Methods**
[image: Success while NOT subscribing Client Methods]

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to mention that I am using **CORS for SignalR** exactly as Jay pointed out below. Its an **MVC Application with a WebAPI controller as well**.

Please help!

Comment: Are you manually setting `jQuery.support.cors` to true? If you manually set jQuery to accept cors it will cause SignalR to fail

Comment: No, I haven't done that. Thank you.

Comment: Could you hook in to the `start().fail()` promise and `console.log(arguments)` ?

Comment: If you have access to the serverside debug, it may be worth  overriding the `onConnected` function on the server and inspecting the `HttpContext` object, to see if the server really is sending back the correct headers

Comment: Jay, thanks for the comments. The start().fail() gives _Error: Error during start request. Stopping the connection._  BTW, hope you've seen the latest console screenshots that I added. Is there anything that I could do, if I find that the correct headers are not sent across from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response status 500 (Internal Server Error) is about a null reference in the OnConnected method of the Hub. Was able to figure that out using the Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

On the front end make sure you are **NOT** setting cors support

```
jQuery.support.cors = true //Do not put this
```

On the server, in your startup class, make sure cors is allowed by adding:

```
  app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration 
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                // EnableJSONP = true
            };
            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

Info on Cors/JSONP support can be found at: [asp net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: On the server side, I've already done that with an additional line like the enabling JSON:                          var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
     {
      // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
      // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
      // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
      EnableJSONP = true
     };

Comment: Have you enabled it in your web config file? and set it to allow when registering routes?
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I would recommend using AJAX to test that cors works outside of your signalR implementation first, then you can narrow down where the problem lies

Comment: Jay, thanks for your time. As I have mentioned earlier, I'm able to connect and call server methods well as long as I don't try to subscribe client methods.

Comment: Jay, I have removed EnableJSONP = true

Comment: if you have EnableJSONP = true in the Startup.cs, you should use `$.connection.hub.start({jsonp:true}).done(...)` on the client

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay for your time.